# How to get only one rounded corner with border-radius htc hack and MSIE v:roundrect?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with partially rounded corners. See the first working example for most browsers:

```
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

You can see that only bottom right corner should be rounded. Natural choice would be adding a [border-radius.htc hack](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser) inside a conditional IE statement:

```
.box {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
}
```

This is not working because border-radius.htc file is only accessing normal border-radius value (this.currentStyle['border-radius']). VML used by the hack is roundrect which only supports one percentage value for arcsize.

So I was wondering if there is any other way around the problem by using some other VML elements?

Another problem is that htc-file doesnt's support borders but that can be fixed with VML's stroked attribute. Nifty corners for example doesn't work well with corners at all.

Answer (score 127):

I was able to get it to work with `border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;` and htc from http://css3pie.com/

Comment: For more Information on the border-radius: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

Comment: An order of corners: **top-left**, **top-right**, **bottom-right**, **bottom-left**

Answer (score 32):

The other solution: `border-bottom-right-radius:10px;` not to make the CPU calculate unneeded border roundings